# how to sort multiple colmuns (more than ten columns) in scala language?

Tags: scala, sorting

how to sort multiple colmuns (more than ten columns) in scala language.
for example:

```
1  2  3 4
4  5  6 3
1  2  1 1
‌2  3  5 10
```

desired output

```
1 2 1 1
1 2 3 3
2 3 5 4
4 5 6 10
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What have you tried? How are you reading the columns (e.g. from a file)? Please don't forget to post your code :)

Comment: yes. from a text file and separator is space

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. You need to make an attempt first and tell us the problems you ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to it.

```
val input = io.Source.fromFile("junk.txt")   // open file
                     .getLines               // load all contents
                     .map(_.split("\\W+"))   // turn rows into Arrays
                     .map(_.map(_.toInt))    // Arrays of Ints

val output = input.toList          // from Iterator to List
                  .transpose       // swap rows/columns
                  .map(_.sorted)   // sort rows
                  .transpose       // swap back

output.foreach(x => println(x.mkString(" ")))  // report results
```

Note: This allows any whitespace between the numbers but it will fail to create the expected `Array[Int]` if it encounters other separators (commas, etc.) or if the line begins with a space.

Also, `transpose` will throw if the rows aren't all the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following algorithm. First alter the dimension of the row and columns. Then sort the rows, then again alter the dimension to bring back original row-column configuration. Here is a sample proof of concept.

```
object SO_42720909 extends App {

  // generating dummy data
  val unsortedData = getDummyData(2, 3)
  prettyPrint(unsortedData)
  println("----------------- ")

  // altering the dimension
  val unsortedAlteredData = alterDimension(unsortedData)
  //  prettyPrint(unsortedAlteredData)

  // sorting the altered data
  val sortedAlteredData = sort(unsortedAlteredData)
  //  prettyPrint(sortedAlteredData)

  // bringing back original dimension
  val sortedData = alterDimension(sortedAlteredData)
  prettyPrint(sortedData)

  def alterDimension(data: Seq[Seq[Int]]): Seq[Seq[Int]] = {
    val col = data.size
    val row = data.head.size // make it safe
    for (i <- (0 until row))
      yield for (j <- (0 until col)) yield data(j)(i)
  }

  def sort(data: Seq[Seq[Int]]): Seq[Seq[Int]] = {
    for (row <- data) yield row.sorted
  }

  def getDummyData(row: Int, col: Int): Seq[Seq[Int]] = {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    for (i <- (1 to row))
      yield for (j <- (1 to col)) yield r.nextInt(100)
  }

  def prettyPrint(data: Seq[Seq[Int]]): Unit = {
    data.foreach(row => {
      println(row.mkString(", "))
    })
  }
}
```